# Recover list names after applying purrr reduce r

Tags: r, list, purrr, names

Is there a way to keep from losing the name attributes of a list after using `purrr::reduce`?

## Example

I have a list:

```
library(tidyverse)
l <- list(A = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                         x = c(1,2,3)),
          B = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                         x = c(4,5,6)),
          C = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                         x = c(7,8,9)))
```

I can join the lists on "ID" using `reduce` and then use `setNames` to name the columns like this.

```
l %>% 
  purrr::reduce(left_join, by = "ID") %>% 
  setNames(c("ID", names(l)))
```

But I would like to take this list and directly pipe it into `purrr::reduce` and then rename the columns "A", "B" and "C" without creating object `l`, but when I do this the list names are no longer available.

## Question

What can I do to the code below to change the names of the column "x" without having to create the list `l` or specify the individual column names?

```
list(A = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                    x = c(1,2,3)),
     B = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                    x = c(4,5,6)),
     C = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                    x = c(7,8,9))) %>% 
  purrr::reduce(left_join, by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `imap` and `set_names` from `purrr` to rename the columns before you merge

```
library(purrr)
list(A = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                    x = c(1,2,3)),
     B = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                    x = c(4,5,6)),
     C = data_frame(ID = c(101, 102, 103),
                    x = c(7,8,9))) %>% 
  imap(.x = ., ~ set_names(.x, c("ID", .y))) %>% 
  reduce(dplyr::left_join, by = "ID")
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     ID     A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   101     1     4     7
#2   102     2     5     8
#3   103     3     6     9
```