# R: Use data frame names for columns after/before applying purrr reduce

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, purrr, names

I already checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965276/recover-list-names-after-applying-purrr-reduce-r), but unfortunately, it does not fit my more complex data.

**Raw Data:**

I have a list named `Total.Scores` with eleven data frames named
`2000-2020` each is containing annual data from 2000 till 2020. Each data frame has a different number of rows but always 12 columns: `ID`, `Category`, `Score.1-9`, and `Year`.

Sample Data:

```
library(purrr)
Total.Scores <- list("2020" = data.frame(ID = c("A2_101", "B3_102", "LO_103", "TT_101"),
                                                          Category = c("blue", "red", "green", "red"),
                                                          Score.1 = c(1,2,3,0),
                                                          Score.2 = c(3,4,5,2),
                                                          Score.3 = c(0,0,1,1),
                                                          Year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)),
                     "2019" = data.frame(ID = c("A2_101", "B3_102", "LO_103"),
                                                          Category = c("blue", "red", "green"),
                                                          Score.1 = c(1,2,3),
                                                          Score.2 = c(3,4,5),
                                                          Score.3 = c(0,0,1),
                                                          Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019)),
                     "2018" = data.frame(ID = c("A2_101", "B3_102", "LO_103", "TT_201","AA_345"),
                                                          Category = c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "purple"),
                                                          Score.1 = c(1,2,3,3,5),
                                                          Score.2 = c(3,4,5,5,3),
                                                          Score.3 = c(0,0,1,3,0),
                                                          Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)),
                     "2017" = data.frame(ID = c("A2_101", "B3_102", "LO_103", "TT_101"),
                                                          Category = c("blue", "red", "green", "red"),
                                                          Score.1 = c(1,2,3,0),
                                                          Score.2 = c(3,4,5,2),
                                                          Score.3 = c(0,0,1,1),
                                                          Year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017)))
```

**Joined Data:**

I combine the data frames from the `Total.Scores` list into the new large data frame `Total.Yearly.Scores` via a `full_join` by `ID` and `Category`:

```
Total.Yearly.Scores <- Total.Scores %>% reduce(full_join, by = c("ID", "Category"))
```

**Result:**

```
# Total.Yearly.Scores

      ID Category Score.1.x Score.2.x Score.3.x Year.x Score.1.y Score.2.y Score.3.y Year.y Score.1.x.x Score.2.x.x Score.3.x.x Year.x.x
1 A2_101     blue         1         3         0   2020         1         3         0   2019           1           3           0     2018
2 B3_102      red         2         4         0   2020         2         4         0   2019           2           4           0     2018
3 LO_103    green         3         5         1   2020         3         5         1   2019           3           5           1     2018
4 TT_101      red         0         2         1   2020        NA        NA        NA     NA          NA          NA          NA       NA
5 TT_201   yellow        NA        NA        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA     NA           3           5           3     2018
6 AA_345   purple        NA        NA        NA     NA        NA        NA        NA     NA           5           3           0     2018
  Score.1.y.y Score.2.y.y Score.3.y.y Year.y.y
1           1           3           0     2017
2           2           4           0     2017
3           3           5           1     2017
4           0           2           1     2017
5          NA          NA          NA       NA
6          NA          NA          NA       NA
```

**Question:**

How can I adjust my code so that the column headers for the `Score.1-9` and `Year` columns incorporate the data frame names of `2000-2020`?
For example, changing them from `Score.1.x` to `Score.1 2020`:

```
# Total.Yearly.Scores

      ID Category Score.1 2020 Score.2 2020 Score.3 2020 Year 2020 Score.1 2019 Score.2 2019 Score.3 2019 Year 2019 Score.1 2018  Score.2 2018  Score.3 2018  Year 2018 
1 A2_101     blue            1            3            0      2020            1            3            0      2019            1             3            0        2018
2 B3_102      red            2            4            0      2020            2            4            0      2019            2             4            0        2018
3 LO_103    green            3            5            1      2020            3            5            1      2019            3             5            1        2018
4 TT_101      red            0            2            1      2020            NA           NA           NA       NA            NA            NA           NA         NA
5 TT_201   yellow            NA           NA           NA       NA            NA           NA           NA       NA            3             5            3        2018
6 AA_345   purple            NA           NA           NA       NA            NA           NA           NA       NA            5             3            0        2018  
  Score.1 2017  Score.2 2017  Score.3 2017  Year 2017 
1            1             3             0       2017
2            2             4             0       2017
3            3             5             1       2017
4            0             2             1       2017
5            NA            NA            NA       NA
6            NA            NA            NA       NA
```

Thanks in advance for the help!
Best regards, Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `rename` before the join

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)  
library(stringr)  
Total.Scores %>% 
    imap(~ {nm1 <- .y
     rename_at(.x, vars(-c("ID", "Category")), ~ str_c(., nm1, sep= ' '))}) %>%
    reduce(full_join, by = c("ID", "Category"))
```

-output

```
 ID Category Score.1 2020 Score.2 2020 Score.3 2020 Year 2020 Score.1 2019 Score.2 2019 Score.3 2019
1 A2_101     blue            1            3            0      2020            1            3            0
2 B3_102      red            2            4            0      2020            2            4            0
3 LO_103    green            3            5            1      2020            3            5            1
4 TT_101      red            0            2            1      2020           NA           NA           NA
5 TT_201   yellow           NA           NA           NA        NA           NA           NA           NA
6 AA_345   purple           NA           NA           NA        NA           NA           NA           NA
  Year 2019 Score.1 2018 Score.2 2018 Score.3 2018 Year 2018 Score.1 2017 Score.2 2017 Score.3 2017 Year 2017
1      2019            1            3            0      2018            1            3            0      2017
2      2019            2            4            0      2018            2            4            0      2017
3      2019            3            5            1      2018            3            5            1      2017
4        NA           NA           NA           NA        NA            0            2            1      2017
5        NA            3            5            3      2018           NA           NA           NA        NA
6        NA            5            3            0      2018           NA           NA           NA        NA
```